# GMGridView selection is overriding

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, gmgridview

[image][image]I got weird problem, while using GMGridView. Actually i'm using GMGridview to show the restaurant tables. If i selected Table1(that means first cell), It should change to redColor(that means it is occupied table). I did this, But my problem is when i select a cell 1(redcolor), that redcolor is showing in all classes whereever i used GMGridview. Thats is completely wrong, without any selection in the another class, it is showing as selected one.

In the images below, if i selected 1, it is showing 7 also selected.....

And my code is

```
- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{



    CGSize size = [self GMGridView:gridView sizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication 
sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];


    GMGridViewCell *cell = [gridView dequeueReusableCell];


    int isOccupied = [[[self.arrayOfoccupiedTables objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"TStatus"] intValue];


    if (!cell)

    {

        cell = [[[GMGridViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];


        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];

        cell.contentView = view;

    }


    [[cell.contentView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];


    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.bounds];

    label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 

UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;

    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:APPFONTLI size:22.0f];

    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;



    if (isOccupied == 100001) {


        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];//redColor];

        //colorWithRed:43.0f/255.0f green:150.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];//GreenColor

        label.text  = [[self.filtredArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"TableName"];


    }else if(isOccupied == 100002) {



        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:43.0f/255.0f green:150.0f/255.0f 
blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

        //colorWithRed:215.0f/255.0f green:215.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];//GreenColor

        label.text  = [[self.filtredArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"TableName"];

    }

    else if(isOccupied == 100003) {

        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:215.0f/255.0f green:215.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];// Yellow Color


        //colorWithRed:229.0f/255.0f green:229.0f/255.0f blue:229.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];//GrayColor

        label.text  = [[self.filtredArray objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"TableName"];

    }
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    return cell;
}

- (void)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView didTapOnItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)position
{

  NSLog(@"Did tap at index %d", position);

    [[SoundManager sharedSoundManager] playSound:SELECTED];

    //[self performSelector:@selector(registerTableToTheServer:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.2];

    [self registerTableToTheServer:[[self filtredArray] objectAtIndex:position]];

    NSInteger tableId   =  [[[[self filtredArray] objectAtIndex:position] objectForKey:@"Table_id"] intValue];

    [self createPlistWithTableId:tableId];

    [_gmGridView reloadData];
}
```

And that to i'm reloading the gridview in viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad also. I didnt find anything useful. Please help me out guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
- (GMGridViewCell *)GMGridView:(GMGridView *)gridView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    
    CGSize size = [self GMGridView:gridView sizeForItemsInInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
    
    GMGridViewCell *cell = [gridView dequeueReusableCell];
    int isOccupied = [[[self.arrayOfoccupiedTables objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:@"TStatus"] intValue];

    if (!cell)  {
        cell = [[[GMGridViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];
             
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
        cell.contentView = view;
    }

   //TRY TO RELOAD THE MG_GRIDVIEW HERE
}
```